SECURITY - Magento Magento Open Source Version 2.4.7-p2
I am not an IT expert. Just wondering if I do install Magento Magento Open Source Version 2.4.7-p2, Do I need to install any extra Security Patches ?
Best Regards,
Daniel

At the time of writing this, it looks like 2.4.7-p2 should be the latest stable, up to date and patched code.  The 2.4.7-p2 was released on August 13th 2024. (less than a week before writing this).
I guess you are good to go without any other known security issues, but you should always be on a lookout for anything that changes.

Here is the Magento schedule for the incoming patches : Magento Release schedule
